# MEAN install not working

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

I am not sure why my MEAN install is not working. I am trying to get a test page on localhost:3000 for a class that I am taking. here is a screenshot of my terminal: 
[my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnsO.png)

Comment: it says -bash: mean: command not found

Comment: also if it means anything when i echo $PATH is says /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 0):

Your must be install yeoman to install and create a [MeanJS](http://meanjs.org/generator.html) project.

The scaffolding tool (you may have already installed it as it is part of the Yeoman tool set). To globally install yo, you will need to use npm:

```
$ npm install -g yo
```

Install the generator, with:

```
$ npm install -g generator-meanjs
```

Finnaly, create a project

```
$ yo meanjs
```

I noticed you're trying to use `mean-cli`. Taking into account that you included the `meanjs` tag, I will respond based on this.

Well, you do not specify what mean framework you're using, I think [Mean.IO](http://mean.io/) is that.